# VBA count for previous column

Tags: vba

I am looking for a solution for the following example. I have a client who sends me a spreadsheet with 321 columns of random length. In row 2, they have a store number. For each column, there is a different store number. I need to insert a blank column in between each column and then copy the store number in the new column the same length of number of cells.

I use the following to add the columns:

```
Sub InsertColumns()
Dim J As Integer, k As Integer
    J = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
'j is the last column
For k = J To 2 Step -1
Range(Cells(1, k), Cells(1, k)).EntireColumn.Insert
Next k
```

I just need the code for count up base on the data in the previous column, copying the value from the previous store and pasting this in the column based on the number of rows of the previous column.

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: I wrote my answer based on what I thought you were asking for, but I see that tigeravatar understood it differently.  If neither of ours produces what you were looking for, can you edit your post to include a brief "before and after" data sample?

Comment: Yeah, I posted right after @techturtle did.  Looks like some clarification is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim cIndex As Long

    For cIndex = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 2 Step -1
        Columns(cIndex + 1).Insert
        Range(Cells(1, cIndex + 1), Cells(Rows.Count, cIndex).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).Value = Cells(2, cIndex).Value
    Next cIndex

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following just below your posted code block:

```
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, (J * 2))).Copy
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=1, Link:=1, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:=False
```

Basically it copies the second row up to the point where you have data (previous counted columns times 2 to account for the added blanks), selects the first blank cell, then does a Paste Special with the "Skip Blanks" attribute turned on.

Comment: That works but only copies the value to the first cell of the column. What i was looking for was a way I could count the number of cells in the first column (A3:lastrow), then paste the value of A2 in the same number of cells in the new column. That's where I am stumped.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it was intended to do based on what I thought you were asking for (*"copying the value from the previous store"*).  That's why we asked for more clarification, but it looks like tigeravatar's version worked for you.